# Как вытащить текст в квадратных скобках (для столбца)

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения, pandas, split

Подскажите, как вытащить текст в квадратных скобках? Какой способ будет работать для всей колонки датафрейма?
(в квадратных скобках хранится название категории)

Например, split() работает, но только для отдельной строки:

```
s = "Обращались ли Вы за помощью в официальные инстанции? [Приобретение технических средств реабилитации]"

s.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
```

Если применить в функции, то выходит ошибка:

Первый вариант:

```
def get_word(col):
    return col.split('[', 1)[1].split(']')[0]
        
df['категория'] = df_21['вопрос'].apply(get_word)
```

Второй вариант:

```
def get_word_2(row):
    s = row['вопрос']
    new =  s.str.split('[')[1].split(']')[0] 
    return new

df_21['категория'] = df_21.apply(get_word_2, axis=1)
```

А варианты с регулярными выражениями возвращают пустой список или ошибку:

```
def get_word_3(row):
    test = row['вопрос']
    test = re.findall(r"\[([А-Яа-я]+)\]", test) 
    return test 

df_21['категория'] = df_21.apply(get_word_3, axis=1)
```

Comment: Первый вариант прекрасно работает. Во втором варианте нужно просто убрать `.str` и тоже всё работает. Покажите ваш датафрейм `df_21` **прямо в вопросе**. И **полный текст ошибок** тоже нужно показывать **прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: В третьем варианте нужно добавить пробел к буквам: `[А-Яа-я ]+`

Answer (score 1):

Всё прекрасно работает с небольшими изменениями. По способам:

1. Прекрасно работает вообще без изменений
2. `.str` не нужен, без него отлично работает
3. К буквам нужно добавить ещё пробел

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def get_word_1(col):
    return col.split('[', 1)[1].split(']')[0]

def get_word_2(row):
    s = row['вопрос']
    return  s.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]

def get_word_3(row):
    test = row['вопрос']
    test = re.findall(r"\[([А-Яа-я ]+)\]", test) 
    return test 

df = pd.DataFrame({'вопрос': ["Обращались ли Вы за помощью в официальные инстанции? [Приобретение технических средств реабилитации]"]})
df['категория_1'] = df['вопрос'].apply(get_word_1)
df['категория_2'] = df.apply(get_word_2, axis=1)
df['категория_3'] = df.apply(get_word_3, axis=1) 
df
```

| index | вопрос | категория_1 | категория_2 | категория_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Обращались ли Вы за помощью в официальные инстанции? [Приобретение технических средств реабилитации] | Приобретение технических средств реабилитации | Приобретение технических средств реабилитации | Приобретение технических средств реабилитации |

Так что ищите проблемы в вашем датафрейме. Который вы должны предоставить по правилам прямо в вопросе, чтобы получить адекватный ответ на свой вопрос. И тексты ошибок тоже нужны для диагностики проблем.

Comment: @ipatev_nn `extract` используется в другом ответе )

Comment: Точно, ссорян =)

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, проще и быстрее использовать [`pandas.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Text': ["Обращались ли Вы за помощью в официальные инстанции? [Приобретение технических средств реабилитации]"]})
df['категория'] = df['Text'].str.extract('\[(.*)\]')
print(df)
```

```
                                                Text                                      категория
0  Обращались ли Вы за помощью в официальные инст...  Приобретение технических средств реабилитации
```

Comment: Думаю стоит смягчить квантификатор сделав его ленивым, так как поведение при [...]...[...] будет не таким как хотелось бы